# I cannot play video in offline mode in giraffe video player, but online mode is working

Tags: android, android-video-player

I cant play video in offline mode means the video in raw folder is not playing in giraffe player it's fine working with online video but when I give the path folder it's show on screen "something error".

My Code:

```
final Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+ R.raw.video);

    videoInfo = new VideoInfo(video)
            .setTitle("Test video") //config title
            .setShowTopBar(true) //show mediaController top bar
            .setPortraitWhenFullScreen(true);
    GiraffePlayer.play(this, videoInfo);
```

The library that I am using for this video playing:

```
api 'com.github.tcking:giraffeplayer2:0.1.25'
```

How would I be able to fix this?

Comment: What is the "something error" that you are receiving?

Comment: this is just a string which is showing on my device screen while i play video